# Stored Procedure trying to convert varchar to int for unknown reason

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL parameters to allow the user to create their own SELECT query using dropdowns in the view. The parameter values are passed to the stored procedure from the view using entity framework in an MVC controller.

I am trying to avoid dynamic SQL, so I have a couple options for doing this.

Here is the method that I ultimately chose:

```
    @topLeftInput varchar(100),
    @topRightInput varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
        Select  * from test
            where 
                CASE @topLeftInput 
                    WHEN 'BasicReturnReasonId' THEN BasicReturnReasonId
                    WHEN 'ClientName' THEN ClientName
                    WHEN 'CreditDeniedReasonId' THEN CreditDeniedReasonId
                    WHEN 'ItemsnotReturnedReasonId' THEN ItemsnotReturnedReasonId
                    WHEN 'ManufacturerId' THEN ManufacturerId
                    WHEN 'ManufacturerOrderNumber' THEN ManufacturerOrderNumber
                    WHEN 'ProductConditionId' THEN ProductConditionId
                                ELSE NULL
                    END
                = @topRightInput;
END
```

The exception is occurring when `@topLeftInput` is `ClientName` or `ManufacturerOrderNumber`. When `@topLeftInput` is equal to either of these, the user can enter the value for `@topRightInput` in a textbox, instead of using a dropdown.

[image]

I am getting an exception that says error converting the varchar value to int. Not sure why it is trying to do that.

In the previous technique I was using, this exception was not happening and it was working perfectly (Just an example for the first option):

```
if @topLeftInput = 'BasicReturnReasonId'
    Begin
        Select * from test
            where BasicReturnReasonId = @topRightInput;
    End
```

Why would changing this if statement method to a `CASE` cause this kind of exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is case statement

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression

Try changing your query like this

```
Select  * 
from test
where 
(@topLeftInput = 'BasicReturnReasonId' and BasicReturnReasonId = @topRightInput)
or
(@topLeftInput = 'ClientName' and ClientName = @topRightInput)
or
(@topLeftInput = 'CreditDeniedReasonId' and CreditDeniedReasonId = @topRightInput)
or
(@topLeftInput = 'ItemsnotReturnedReasonId' and ItemsnotReturnedReasonId = @topRightInput)
or 
..
```

or you have to explicitly convert the `integer` columns to `varchar` to avoid implicit conversion error

```
CASE @topLeftInput 
                    WHEN 'BasicReturnReasonId' THEN cast(BasicReturnReasonId as varchar(50))
                    WHEN 'ClientName' THEN ClientName
                    WHEN 'CreditDeniedReasonId' THEN cast(CreditDeniedReasonId as varchar(50))
                    WHEN 'ItemsnotReturnedReasonId' THEN cast(ItemsnotReturnedReasonId as varchar(50))
                    WHEN 'ManufacturerId' THEN cast(ManufacturerId as varchar(50))
                    WHEN 'ManufacturerOrderNumber' THEN cast(ManufacturerOrderNumber as varchar(50))
                    WHEN 'ProductConditionId' THEN cast(ProductConditionId as varchar(50))
                                ELSE NULL
                    END
```

Comment: Interestingly, I only got this to work with the second method. I was still getting the conversion error with the first.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a case expression must resolve to only one type.  It can't return an `integer` in some cases and a `varchar` in others.  When you have mixed types in your possible return values, SQL Server picks the type that has the highest [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  In your case statement it is `int`.

You have to make sure that all possible return values can be converted to the type of highest precedence.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. So this should work if I separate it into two `CASE` statements

Comment: Yeah, two case statements checking equivalence separated by an OR should do it. Or you can convert all values to varchar in the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression returns exactly one type determined when the code is compiled, based on the type precedence rules of the `where` clauses.

In other words, you cannot do what you want with a `case`.  Just use separate conditions:

```
where (@topLeftInput = 'BasicReturnReasonId' AND @topRightInput = BasicReturnReasonId) or
      (@topLeftInput = 'ClientName' AND @topRightInput = ClientName) or
      . . .
```

For performance reasons (particularly if you have indexes), dynamic SQL is a better way to go.